# Interference between fermions in square well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, interference, fermions, pauli-exclusion-principle

Are identical fermions in a square well interfering with each other?

My qm class taught the double slit experiment using single particle wave functions. Unfortunately, I do not have a good reference that describes this, and I could not find similar webpages on the internet. (would appreciate it if anyone has any good source, but that is a side note). We are now doing identical particles. I know the fermionic symmetrization requirement $\psi_a(x_1)\psi_b(x_2)-\psi_a(x_2)\psi_b(x_1)$. I want to have a visual for how this looks when you involve spin.

Let the particles have single-particle wavefunctions including spinors, like $\Psi_a(x_1)=\psi_a(x_1)\chi(x_1)$. I think I should be able to substitute every $\psi$ with $\Psi$ in the old symmetrization requirement, to make a two-particle wave function.

Now I become uncertain. I want to take different spinors, such that both my fermions in the square well can occupy a ground state-like wave function. I know this should have energy $2E_0$. I want to choose spinors $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$. This should make my wavefunctions differ by a phase $\pi$. So does the symmetrization requirement become an interference equation? What happens if the phase is chosen such that the symmetrization gives $\psi(x_1,x_2)=0$? Do you need to disallow that as an invalid pair of states $\psi_a\chi_a$ and $\psi_b\chi_b$?

There may be many mistakes in my reasoning, so here is an alternate question that could resolve my confusion if it is answered: how can we write solutions for two identical fermions in a square well, while including spinors (i.e. using pauli exclusion but allowing two particles to occupy each state by having different spin)?

Comment: There's some relevant discussion [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105907/21441).

Comment: Have a look at [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slater_determinant).